# How to retrieve the complete array element or index from the multi-dimensional array when its some of the key and values are known

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array [image: arrays of array elements] which consists of arrays. So, now suppose I want to retrieve the `sku` and `price` whose
`key` `value` is `2=>5` and `3=>7` so it should return `price=>13` and `sku=>bc` i.e. that array whose index is at `1` in the array.

Comment: Just simply loop through the array and check for the values you search for and if they match you know that you have the array you looked for.

Comment: @Rizier123 so I am looping through the array but how to search for key values are same and key values are dynamic sometime there maybe more than 2 keys to compare and sometime it is less

Comment: Could you alter your array slightly so that your comparison keys (2 and 3) are in its own array. You can then foreach through these for your comparison?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I would probably try the following (Same as Riziers comment)

```
foreach($array as $key => $item) {
    if($item[2] == 5 && $item[3] == 7) {
        // return price
        return $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: return $item would be better, OP wants both price & sku

Answer (score 1):

There is a function [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), which does what you want but for simple values. You can define your own function that will take not `$needle`, but callable predicate:

```
function array_search_callback(callable $predicate, array $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if ($predicate($item)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Having this function your example can be done like this:

```
$key = array_search_callback(function ($item) {
    return $item[2] === '5' && $item[3] === '7';
}, $array);

$result = $key === false ? null : $array[$key];
```

I could simply return an item from the search function. But to be consistent with the original search function, I am returning the index.

As `array_search_callback` takes callable as an argument you can provide any criteria you want without the need of modifying the function itself.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/829709c8fcb96ba309d6ebf676050013ae5a7ca8).